# Insert Button for multilevel numbering

Tags: excel, vba

I need a insert button for multilevel numbering VBA like below:

[image]

Choose task level and click button "next" will insert that level. The excel interface I want is as follow:

[image]

And this is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub btNew_Click()

Dim work As Worksheet
Set work = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim lv1 As Worksheet
Set lv1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lv1")

Dim lv2 As Worksheet
Set lv2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lv2")

Dim lv3 As Worksheet
Set lv3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lv3")



'Task
Dim A As String
If (cbTask = "Task" And ActiveCell.Value <> "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Int(Max + 1)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).IndentLevel = 0

work.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

lv1.Range("A1").Value = 1
lv2.Range("A1").Value = 1
lv3.Range("A1").Value = 1


ElseIf (cbTask = "Task" And ActiveCell.Value = "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.Value = Int(Max + 1)
ActiveCell.IndentLevel = 0

work.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

lv1.Range("A1").Value = 1
lv2.Range("A1").Value = 1
lv3.Range("A1").Value = 1

End If

'Task lv1
If (cbTask = "Task-lv1" And ActiveCell.Value <> "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Str(Max) + "." + Str(lv1.Range("A1").Value)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).IndentLevel = 1

lv1.Range("A1").Value = Int(lv1.Range("A1").Value) + 1

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
lv2.Range("A1").Value = 1
lv3.Range("A1").Value = 1

ElseIf (cbTask = "Task-lv1" And ActiveCell.Value = "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Value = Str(Max) + "." + Str(lv1.Range("A1").Value)
ActiveCell.IndentLevel = 1

lv1.Range("A1").Value = Int(lv1.Range("A1").Value) + 1

work.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
lv2.Range("A1").Value = 1
lv3.Range("A1").Value = 1

End If

'Task lv2
If (cbTask = "Task-lv2" And ActiveCell.Value <> "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Str(Max) + "." + Str(lv1.Range("A1").Value - 1) + "." + Str(lv2.Range("A1").Value)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).IndentLevel = 2

lv2.Range("A1").Value = Int(lv2.Range("A1").Value) + 1

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
lv3.Range("A1").Value = 1

ElseIf (cbTask = "Task-lv2" And ActiveCell.Value = "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Value = Str(Max) + "." + Str(lv1.Range("A1").Value - 1) + "." + Str(lv2.Range("A1").Value)
ActiveCell.IndentLevel = 2

lv2.Range("A1").Value = Int(lv2.Range("A1").Value) + 1

work.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
lv3.Range("A1").Value = 1

End If

'Task lv3
If (cbTask = "Task-lv3" And ActiveCell.Value <> "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Str(Max) + "." + Str(lv1.Range("A1").Value - 1) + "." + Str(lv2.Range("A1").Value - 1) + "." + Str(lv3.Range("A1").Value)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).IndentLevel = 3
lv3.Range("A1").Value = Int(lv3.Range("A1").Value) + 1

work.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ElseIf (cbTask = "Task-lv3" And ActiveCell.Value = "") Then

A = ActiveCell.Address
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(work.Range("A1:" & A))
ActiveCell.Value = Str(Max) + "." + Str(lv1.Range("A1").Value - 1) + "." + Str(lv2.Range("A1").Value - 1) + "." + Str(lv3.Range("A1").Value)
ActiveCell.IndentLevel = 3
lv3.Range("A1").Value = Int(lv3.Range("A1").Value) + 1

work.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

ufTask.Hide
End Sub
```

The problem I encounter is that this code can only add task levels in a top-down order. If added in a random position, it will no longer be logical like in positions 4.1.1.2 and 4.1.2.3.

Please help me improve the code so that I can add tasks in every position and at every level but still satisfy the sorting logic. Thank a lot.